How to Dismiss Notifications on Multiple Devices When Clicked on One in Firebase?
Context:
I have an app that uses Firebase to send notifications to users. I have an account logged in on two devices (Device A and Device B). When a notification is sent, it is received on both devices.
Problem
When I click on the notification on one device (say Device A), I want the notification on the other device (Device B) to be automatically dismissed, similar to how notifications work in apps like WhatsApp or Facebook Messenger.
Current Setup

Devices: Multiple devices logged into the same account
Notifications: Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM)

Questions
How can I achieve the functionality where clicking on a notification on one device dismisses the same notification on another device using Firebase? Is there a specific pattern or feature in Firebase that supports this behavior? What would be the best way to implement this?
Any code snippets or references would be appreciated!

https://medium.com/@sebastianosiski/implementing-removable-remote-notifications-on-ios-a17d74832bde

@Paulw11 Thanks for the iOS reference. I'm also looking for an Android reference.
